# Finding an integer key of a Python dict that is closest to a given integer

Tags: python

I have a dictionary where the keys are integers.  I have another integer.  I want to find the value corresponding to the key in the dict that is closest to the given integer.  Is there an efficient way to do this?

Maybe a different data structure (binary tree) would be more efficient?

Comment: Better always provide a simple example.

Comment: A simple method would be to iterate through the keys of your dictionary and see which one is closest to your integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dd = {2:'x', 6:'y', 100000:'z', 77:'w'}
ikey = 99
low = max([d for d in dd if d<= ikey])
high = min([d for d in dd if d>= ikey])
nearkey = low if ikey - low <= high - ikey else high
nearkey

77
```

Answer (score 2):

**Binary Search Tree**

Your suggestion of a binary search tree got me thinking about how I would implement it, so I went ahead and did it. If I'm not mistaken, this offers an O(log n) complexity during lookup but takes more setup time (linear instead of constant), which means it's only optimal in more read-intensive situations.

```
from math import inf


class RangeMap:
    def __init__(self, dictionary, minimum=-inf, maximum=inf):
        assert dictionary
        self._dictionary = dictionary
        self.min, self.max = minimum, maximum
        self._generate_tree()

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self._dictionary[key]
        self._generate_tree()

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        current = self._tree
        while current:
            if item < current.lower:
                current = current.before
            elif item <= current.upper:
                return current.value
            else:
                current = current.after
        raise Exception("Tree not constructed properly")

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._dictionary[key] = value
        self._generate_tree()

    def _generate_tree(self):
        range_mapping = [(((p + c) / 2, (c + n) / 2), self._dictionary[c])
                         for p, c, n in self._iterate_keys()]
        self._tree = RangeMap.Node(range_mapping)

    def _iterate_keys(self):
        keys = sorted(self._dictionary.keys())
        return zip([self.min] + keys[:-1], keys, keys[1:] + [self.max])

    class Node:
        def __init__(self, range_mapping):
            assert range_mapping
            middle = len(range_mapping) // 2
            (self.lower, self.upper), self.value = range_mapping[middle]
            before, after = range_mapping[:middle], range_mapping[middle + 1:]
            self.before = RangeMap.Node(before) if before else None
            self.after = RangeMap.Node(after) if after else None
```

You would use it as such (ties in distance round up [a decision I arrived at entirely so __getitem__ would not break with infinity--to switch that change the `<=` in __getitem__ to `<`]):

```
>>> dictionary = {
...     4: 'four',
...     8: 'eight',
...     15: 'fifteen',
...     16: 'sixteen',
...     23: 'twenty-three',
...     42: 'forty-two'
... }
>>> range_map = RangeMap(dictionary)
>>> range_map[11]
'eight'
>>> range_map[12]
'fifteen'
>>> range_map[15]
'fifteen'
>>> range_map[16]
'sixteen'
>>> range_map[19]
'sixteen'
```

**My Brother's Idea**

I asked my non-programmer brother how he would tackle the problem, and he came up with checking outwards from your desired key (I put it to code).

```
def approximate(dictionary, key):
    assert dictionary and all(isinstance(k, int) for k in dictionary)
    i = 0
    while True:
        if key + i in dictionary:
            return dictionary[key + i]
        if key - i in dictionary:
            return dictionary[key - i]
        i += 1
```

I thought I would include this because it could be a good solution if the integers you're looking up are always going to be close to the keys of your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Best you're going to get on this is probably O(n) runtime.

```
def closestKey(dic, key):
    diff = {k:abs(k - key) for k in dic}
    return min(diff, key=diff.get)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any other way to do it other than iterating over the entire dictionary and then seeing which key was the closest by recording min_diff, as well as the key itself as variables.

Alternatively, you could try using an ordered dict to save some time, but either way it'll run in linear time.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: def lookforkey(mykey, dd):
     ...:     """ returns mykey if present in dd
     ...:         otherwise the nearest key
     ...:         which could be either greater or less
     ...:         than mykey
     ...:     """
     ...:     nearkey = next(iter(dd))
     ...:     bestdist = abs(nearkey - mykey)
     ...:     for ikey in dd:
     ...:             dist = abs(mykey - ikey)
     ...:             if bestdist > dist:
     ...:                 bestdist = dist
     ...:                 nearkey = ikey
     ...:                 if ikey == mykey:
     ...:                     return ikey
     ...:     return nearkey
     ...:  

In [2]: dd = {2: 'x', 6: 'y', 77: 'w', 100000: 'z'}
In [3]: lookforkey(-10, dd)
Out[3]: 2
In [4]: lookforkey(6, dd)
Out[4]: 6
In [5]: lookforkey(76, dd)
Out[5]: 77
In [6]: lookforkey(999, dd)
Out[7]: 77
In [8]: lookforkey(999999, dd)
Out[9]: 100000
```

even tho it's longer, this is more efficeint than min/max solutions which still process the keys twice.  here, if there is an exact match there is no need to continue looking